# gmail not load external css for send email templates

Tags: php, css, email, gmail

I need to Send mail using phpmailer class and html email templates. php mailer send successful email templates but in gmail i cant see template. i think gmail no loaded external css.

template [HERE](http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/basic.html)

what's my problem ? how do fix this and show full template in gmail?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gmail preprocessor cuts all in `<head>` and after `</body>` content.

All you have to do is to move your styles inline, you can use free tools like:

- http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
- http://premailer.dialect.ca/
- http://inliner.cm/

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

While you technically can link to an external stylesheet in an email, any respectable email provider will block external shtylesheets. You need to do them inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query(select * from table_name)
$table="";

$table .="<table border='1'  style='background-color:#C0C0C0;' >
    <tr>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Agent Name</th>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Count of  VOICE - Agent Name</th>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Average of Total Time</th>
     </tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

          $table .="<tr>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['agent_name'] . "</td>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['name_count'] . "</td>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['total_aht'] . "</td>";
      }
       $table .="</tr>";
         $table .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Total</td><td bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>$y</td>
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject="hii";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:<abc@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
$mail=mail($to,$subject, $table,$headers);
    ?>
```